# Type of argument not known in local `macrolet`

Tags: macros, common-lisp

In this example code

```
(defvar mat (make-array (list 5 3)
                        :initial-contents '((1 2 3)
                                            (4 5 6)
                                            (7 8 9)
                                            (10 11 12)
                                            (13 14 15))))

(defun mk-idx (dims dim)
  (loop
     for i below (length dims)
     if (= i dim) collect 1
     else collect 0))

(defun loop-over-dim (ary dim)
  (macrolet ((expan (a d)
               (let* ((dims (array-dimensions a))
                      (dim-max (nth d dims))
                      (sel (mk-idx dims d))
                      (i (gensym)))
                 `(loop
                     for ,i below ,dim-max
                     collect (aref ,a ,@(substitute i 1 sel))))))
    (expan ary dim)))
```

I try to access a matrix with one dimension fixed (currently at the `0` coordinate). So `(loop-over-dim mat 0) ;; => (1 4 7 10 13)`; at least that's the intention.

However, when trying to compile it SBCL tells me that

> The value
>          ARY
>        is not of type
>          ARRAY

The style-warning above the error says that the arguments to `loop-over-dim` are unused. But they are used in the bindings of the `macrolet`.

**So, apart from stylistic considerations, why do I get the error that `ARY` is not an array?**

I already tried moving the `let*` outside of the `macrolet` but with the same results (error).

I also tried wrapping `loop-over-dim` inside an `eval-when`, but no dice.

Maybe `macrolet` (or macros in general) is (are) the wrong tool(s) for this job? 
(see [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm#macrolet),

> [...] but the consequences are undefined if the local macro definitions reference any local variable or function bindings that are visible in that lexical environment.

)

Comment: check the argument type of A. It‘s a symbol. Why is that? Remember: macros compute code from code.

Comment: Ok, I think it fell into place. So `macrolet` cannot access vars from the lexical environment (I think the hyperspec says so): Are macros definitely the wrong choice here?

Comment: There is no lexical environment when the macro gets expanded. The compiler expands the macro and the function LOOP-OVER-DIM hasn't been called yet. There is no binding for ARY to an array, because the function hasn't been called yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros work on syntax and thus `a` and `d` get bound to the symbols `ary` and `dim` and are of course not anything else than symbols that will be variables that evaluate to arrays and numbers after the macro has done its work and the expanded code actually runs.

The expansion can be done at compile time so long before you call the function. You should loose the macrolet completely and do the logic runtime in the function.

Comment: "Doing it at runtime" would then necessitate `apply`, i.e. `(apply #'aref ary '(1 0))`, wouldn't it? But `apply` has some limit, doesn't it?

Comment: @Aroob Yes, but that is what `apply` is for. The limit on length of last argument is the same as the limit on number of arguments in a call. eg. if `apply` fails your macro would have failed had it worked. You can evaluate `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` to see how many arguments you may have and it is guaranteed to be at least 50. In 64 bit SBCL the limit is more than four quintillion, but I guess that 50 would suffice in 99% of the programmers need.

Answer (score 2):

A macro sees code. You cannot ask the source code what bindings it will have in the future.

You can just call DESCRIBE to see what the value of `a` is.
`a` has the symbol `ary` as a value. `array-dimensions` expects an actually array as an argument, not a symbol.

```
CL-USER 8 > (defun loop-over-dim (ary dim)
              (macrolet ((expan (a d)
                           (describe a)
                           nil))
                (expan ary dim)))
LOOP-OVER-DIM

CL-USER 9 > (compile 'loop-over-dim)

ARY is a SYMBOL
NAME          "ARY"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 115/256 internal, 0/4 external>
```